# USBManager hasPermission returns false if the app is sent to background after start

Tags: android, permissions, usb

I have this code that runs when the app starts (in MainActivity's onCreate), and checks if I have permission for a USB device:

```
        UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
        Set<String> keySet = deviceList.keySet();

        for(String key : keySet)
        {
            if(deviceList.get(key).getProductId()==24577 && deviceList.get(key).getVendorId()==1027)
            {
                if( !manager.hasPermission(deviceList.get(key))){
```

I have this in manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>
```

If I run the app normally, hasPermission returns true and everything runs ok.

The problem is that another app starts mine, and after that, starts another app, so my app is in foreground just a few milliseconds. In that case, hasPermission returns false.

Why? and how can I avoid this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the app wasn't enough time in foreground. Sometimes onCreate of the mainActivity wasn't even called.

I ended bringing my app to foreground, complete the activity onCreate, and sending it back to background